# Block access to the server from public IP with iptables

Tags: centos, firewall, iptables

I have 2 servers, I configured one server for `http` and `php` (the name is: web ) and  another one for `mysql` (the name is: db).

In both of these servers, I have public and private IPs.
I wanted to have these rules:

1. change the ssh port of `web` server to `1234`. (I made this change in the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` already)
2. block all requests to the `web` public interface, except 80, 443, and 1234.
3. block all requests to the `db` public interface.
4. block all requests to the `db` private interface, except 22 and 3306 from `web`  private interface.

`web` private ip: 192.168.0.110

`db` private ip: 192.168.0.111

So I wrote these rules for iptables.

**firewall.sh on the `db`**

```
#!/bin/bash
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.0.110 -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.0.110 -p tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
```

**firwall.sh on the `web`**

```
#!/bin/bash
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 1234 -j ACCEPT
```

But after running these rules, my connection to the server will be lost completely and also these two servers cannot have communication with each other.

where is my problem?

Comment: You're blocking inbound traffic.  `Output` is for traffic originating from the server, `Input` or `Forward` would need to be allowed, depending on the network setup.  Also, I assumed you're using `1234` as a placeholder for the real SSH port, but if not, it should not be `1234`.  I personally would change it to something north of 40k, as port scanners usually won't scan every port, so the higher the better IMO.  A better way would be to utilize a redirect on the router so you're not exposing the SSH port directly to WAN _(i.e. say redirect `tcp:59317` to `tcp:1234`)_

Comment: @JW0914 thanks for your comment, yes `1234` is just a sample. so your mean is that should I write `iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --dport 1234 -j ACCEPT` and other rules for `FORWARD` too ?

Comment: No, the SSH redirect would be done on the WAN facing router, _not_ on the the server (WAN `tcp:59317` to VLAN `tcp:1234`).  The inability to access is due `INPUT` and `FORWARD` on the server being dropped, as at least one needs to be allowed, but which one is determinate on your server's network setup.  I would also highly recommend not exposing the server directly to WAN, but doing so via a router... no server should ever be directly exposed to WAN without a router in front of it IMO, and there should be highly restrictive `iptables` rules on the router for traffic to the server(s).

Comment: `INPUT` is not being dropped. The `iptables -P` command just sets the policy (catch-all) rule for the `INPUT` chain. Also, I would make sure the firewall rules are flushed at the start of the script with `iptables -F`.